# Find multiple input in each div and push value to some format

Tags: jquery

I want to get value from input in each div to some format
something like this

```
[
 {"room_type_name":"Room1","room_number":10,"avg_price":"1000"},
 {"room_type_name":"Room2","room_number":20,"avg_price":"2000"}
]
```

This is my HTML

```
<div class="clone_item"> // first Div
  <input class="form-control" name="room_type_name[0]" type="text" value="Room1">                               
  <input class="form-control" name="room_number[0]" type="number" value="10">
  <input class="form-control" name="avg_price[0]" type="number" value="1000"
</div>

<div class="clone_item"> // second Div
  <input class="form-control" name="room_type_name[1]" type="text" value="Room2">                                
  <input class="form-control" name="room_number[1]" type="number" value="20">
  <input class="form-control" name="avg_price[1]" type="number" value="2000">
</div>
```

and this is my javascript

```
var room_array = [];
var i = 0;
var temp_obj = {};
var len =  $(".clone_item :input").length;
$(".clone_item :input").each(function(e){
        var index = this.name.split('[').pop().split(']')[0]; // get number from xxxx[0]
        var name = this.name.split('[')[0];

        temp_obj[name] =  this.value;

        if(i == index || e === (len - 1)) {
            temp_obj[name] =  this.value;
            room_array.push(temp_obj);
            temp_obj = [];
            i++;
        }
    });
```

problem is $(".clone_item :input") is run for 6 times 
Is it have better way to use $(".clone_item :input").each?

Comment: what's exactly your problem?

Comment: i think you should use each loop on div which have class clone_item then use child selector with name to select children of each div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the `clone_item` *instead of looping through inputs* then use`.find()` inputs with `name^` selector .. `^` means starts with

```js
var Items_array = [];
$(".clone_item").each(function(e){
    var This = $(this),
        Room_type_name_val = This.find("[name^='room_type_name']").val(),
        Room_number_val = This.find("[name^='room_number']").val(),
        Room_avg_price_val = This.find("[name^='avg_price']").val();
     var obj = {
        "room_type_name" : Room_type_name_val,
        "room_number" : Room_number_val,
        "avg_price" : Room_avg_price_val
     }
     Items_array.push(obj);
});

console.log(Items_array);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="clone_item">
  <input class="form-control" name="room_type_name[0]" type="text" value="Room1">                               
  <input class="form-control" name="room_number[0]" type="number" value="10">
  <input class="form-control" name="avg_price[0]" type="number" value="1000"
</div>

<div class="clone_item">
  <input class="form-control" name="room_type_name[1]" type="text" value="Room2">                                
  <input class="form-control" name="room_number[1]" type="number" value="20">
  <input class="form-control" name="avg_price[1]" type="number" value="2000">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple implemetation would be to iterate over `clone_itme` and use `.find()` to get the `<input>`s and assign their values/attribute to `temp_obj` and then push  it to `room_array`

```js
var room_array = [];


$(".clone_item").each(function(i, item) {
  var temp_obj = {};
  $(item).find('input').each(function(j, input){
    temp_obj[input.name.replace(/\[\d\]/, '')] = input.value;
  });
  room_array.push(temp_obj);
});

console.log(room_array);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clone_item"> // first Div
  <input class="form-control" name="room_type_name[0]" type="text" value="Room1" />                               
  <input class="form-control" name="room_number[0]" type="number" value="10" />
  <input class="form-control" name="avg_price[0]" type="number" value="1000" />
</div>

<div class="clone_item"> // second Div
  <input class="form-control" name="room_type_name[1]" type="text" value="Room2">                                
  <input class="form-control" name="room_number[1]" type="number" value="20">
  <input class="form-control" name="avg_price[1]" type="number" value="2000">
</div>
```